# Why is my text overflowing

Tags: css, html, overflow

Im having som weird overflow with my text on this site:

http://skole.thebekker.dk/tutorials/?p=test
The 2nd last paragraph...

HTML & CSS source here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mqQEu/

Comment: Which text is overflowing in what way? There's not much to go on here..

Comment: because you are using <pre> tag...

Comment: What's the problem? [Looks fine](http://imgur.com/AQiMZ) on `Chrome 21.0.1180.79`

Comment: At first I'm sorry this is not a anwser, but I do not have the comment btn. But when I check your site in Google Chrome(v21.0.1180.75) on my Mac I do not see any problems. But I agree with you that there is a problem with the site where you are testing. Maybe you can come with a better error description? Best
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
white-space: normal;
```

to your paragraph css `p {}` and your text will wrap better.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped all of you page content in [PRE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tags.  PRE is preformatted text which uses the formatting from the source rather than that defined in the markup.  It shouldn't be used in this way and is typically used for unusual formatting or code samples.

Remove this tag and then fix your line spacing and it will work

Comment: I use fread to load from plain text into the site.
so to get the line breaks without adding br's everywhere, i use the pre. so can i style my way out of it?

Comment: I don't think so.  What is the issue with using the BR tag? The file must contain the other HTML markup?

Comment: Exactly.. so if i add br to the freads text, it adds br to lines with html tags...

I know it is a bad way to get content, but i was just playing with some stuff :)